# Fast string array - Cython

Tags: python, arrays, string, cython, python-2.x

Having following hypothetical code:

```
cdef extern from "string.h":
    int strcmp(char* str1, char* str2)

def foo(list_str1, list_str2):
    cdef unsigned int i, j
    c_arr1 = ??
    c_arr2 = ??
    for i in xrange(len(list_str1)):
        for j in xrange(len(list_str2)):
            if not strcmp(c_arr1[i], c_arr2[j]):
                do some funny stuff
```

is there some way how to convert the lists to c arrays?

I have read and tried [Cython - converting list of strings to char **](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665177/cython-converting-list-of-strings-to-char) but that only throws errors.

Comment: Added recently Python 3 [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69661304/941531) of similar task, maybe you're interested in reading it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're on Python 3, here's an update to @falsetru's answer (untested on Python 2).

```
cdef extern from "Python.h":
    char* PyUnicode_AsUTF8(object unicode)

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.string cimport strcmp

cdef char ** to_cstring_array(list_str):
    cdef char **ret = <char **>malloc(len(list_str) * sizeof(char *))
    for i in xrange(len(list_str)):
        ret[i] = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(list_str[i])
    return ret

def foo(list_str1, list_str2):
    cdef unsigned int i, j
    cdef char **c_arr1 = to_cstring_array(list_str1)
    cdef char **c_arr2 = to_cstring_array(list_str2)

    for i in range(len(list_str1)):
        for j in range(len(list_str2)):
            if i != j and strcmp(c_arr1[i], c_arr2[j]) == 0:
                print(i, j, list_str1[i])
    free(c_arr1)
    free(c_arr2)

foo(['hello', 'python', 'world'], ['python', 'rules'])
```

---

**Warning:** The pointer returned by `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` is cached in the parent unicode-object. Which has two consequences:

1. this pointer is only valid as long as the parent unicode-object is alive. Accessing it afterwards leads to undefined behavior (e.g. possible segmentation fault).
2. The caller of the `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` **isn't** responsible for the freeing the memory.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning, that since Python 3.7 it is `const char * PyUnicode_AsUTF8(...)` https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8

Comment: Thank you, please edit the answer if you feel it needs correction!

Answer (score 17):

Try following code. `to_cstring_array` function in the following code is what you want.

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.string cimport strcmp
from cpython.string cimport PyString_AsString

cdef char ** to_cstring_array(list_str):
    cdef char **ret = <char **>malloc(len(list_str) * sizeof(char *))
    for i in xrange(len(list_str)):
        ret[i] = PyString_AsString(list_str[i])
    return ret

def foo(list_str1, list_str2):
    cdef unsigned int i, j
    cdef char **c_arr1 = to_cstring_array(list_str1)
    cdef char **c_arr2 = to_cstring_array(list_str2)

    for i in xrange(len(list_str1)):
        for j in xrange(len(list_str2)):
            if i != j and strcmp(c_arr1[i], c_arr2[j]) == 0:
                print i, j, list_str1[i]
    free(c_arr1)
    free(c_arr2)

foo(['hello', 'python', 'world'], ['python', 'rules'])
```

Comment: `PyString_AsString` is python2 only, so this solution will not work for python3

Comment: @ead, Beside `PyString_AsString`, there are `xrange` calls in OP's code. So I thought it's okay to assume it's python 2 code. Any suggestion to make this solution work both in python 2/3 is welcome.

Comment: I have found out that in Py3 `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` is supposed to be used but I run into error:  _Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference_. When I factorized the code assigning `PyUnicode_AsUTF8(list_str[i])` to a temp variable, I run into another error: _'PyUnicode_AsUTF8' is not a constant, variable or function identifier_. I have no clue how to proceed at this point.

Comment: It's worth making clear that the memory for the stored `char*` is owned by the Python strings so is only valid while the Python strings are still alive. It's fine in this question, but I came here from a linked question that had copied the code and run into problems